# How to compact python code?

Tags: python, dictionary

so I'm trying to make this search function that shows the person's horoscope when name is entered. I did it the manual way with 4 names, and I know there's a way to compact the code with the dictionary that I have(but not using), but I can't remember.

---

```
Horoscopes = { 
    "A": "Scorpio",
    "B": "Gemini",
    "J": "Sagittarius",
    "P": "Gemini",
   }

def horoscope(name):
    if name == "A" or name == "a":
        print ("Hello " + name + ", you are a Scorpio!")
        print("Welcome to the Horoscope Search!")
        name = input("What is your name? ")
        horoscope(name)
    elif name == "B" or name == "b":
        print ("Hello " + name + ", you are a Gemini!")
        print("Welcome to the Horoscope Search!")
        name = input("What is your name? ")
        horoscope(name)
    elif name == "J" or name == "j":
        print ("Hello " + name + ", you are a Sagittarius!")
        print("Welcome to the Horoscope Search!")
        name = input("What is your name? ")
        horoscope(name)
    elif name == "P" or name == "p":
        print ("Hello " + name + ", you are a Gemini!")
        print("Welcome to the Horoscope Search!")
        name = input("What is your name? ")
        horoscope(name)
    else:
        print ("Sorry " + name + ", you are not registered in our 
        system!")
        print("Welcome to the Horoscope Search!")
        name = input("What is your name? ")
        horoscope(name)

print("Welcome to the Horoscope Search!")
name = input("What is your name? ")
horoscope(name)
```

Comment: Could you clarify your issue, and what your goal is, as your question is not entirely clear in terms of what you are looking to acheive.

Comment: Hi, I'm looking to compact the whole function chunk into just one "if" and "else". So the if would probably be something like if the name was present in the dictionary, then the name of the person would be printed along with the value which is the horoscope

Comment: See what @RacezeQ did. The best method to compact would be to look for the name in the dictionary and return the value associated with that name.

Answer (score 1):

You should define your dictionary with keys starting from small letter, so you can parse all answers to lower letters and compare it this way:

```
Horoscopes = { 
    "a": "Scorpio",
    "b": "Gemini",
    "j": "Sagittarius",
    "p": "Gemini",
}

def horoscope(name):
    if name.lower() in Horoscopes:
        print("Hello " + name + " you are a " + Horoscopes[name.lower()] + "!")
    else:
        print("Sorry " + name + ", you are not registered in our system!")
```

Comment: How do I write the "if" so that if the name does not appear in the dictionary, then the code will run else

Comment: If not name.lower() in Horoscopes:
print("Sorry " + name + ", you are not in the system!")
else:
print("Hello " + name + " you are a " + Horoscopes[name.lower()] + "!")

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with something like so:

```
horoscopes = {
    "Angelina": "Scorpio",
    "Bernice": "Gemini",
    "Jessica": "Sagittarius",
    "Peniel": "Gemini",
   }

print("Welcome to the Horoscope Search!")
name = input("What is your name? ")

if name in horoscopes:  # If name is a key in horoscopes dict
    print("Your Horoscope is {}!".format(horoscopes[name]))
```

Please note this is a case sensitive check for a given name in horoscopes, i.e. if a name is input as 'angelina', it will not match to the dictionary key 'Angelina'. To account for this, if dictionary keys were known to be in **lower** case, one might use the string method `.lower()`:

```
name = input("What is your name? ").lower()
```

This way no matter how the name is entered, there will still be a match.

If you wanted the user to be prompted until a valid name was entered, then:

```
horoscopes = {
    "angelina": "Scorpio",
    "bernice": "Gemini",
    "jessica": "Sagittarius",
    "peniel": "Gemini",
   }

print("Welcome to the Horoscope Search!")

while True:  # Until a name is matched to horoscopes
    name = input("What is your name? ").lower()

    if name in horoscopes:  # If name is a key in horoscopes dict
        print("Your Horoscope is {}!".format(horoscopes[name]))
        break  # A valid name has been entered, break from loop
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid name!")
```